# My Harbor Breeze fan stopped working, the lights still go on

Tags: electrical

My harbor breeze fan stopped working but the lights still go on. What should I do

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post to add more detail about your wiring and the problem. What does "stopped working" mean? With the wall switch? With a pull chain? With a remote control? It's hard to help knowing so little.

Comment: Hi, this is to prevent guesses for answers. Once you have edited, the question to provide more information, others will vote to open it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which model you have, but most ceiling light/fan combos have separate switches (pull chains) for each one. Sometimes they're also wired to two separate wall switches. Additionally, the fans have a switch to select rotation direction. Exercise applicable fan switches to make sure one is not stuck in a neutral position or intermittent. Next, assuming you know how, you could make sure you have power to the switches, then to the motor.